# TYPO3 Menu - Different layout for specific uid

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In my main menu, I need everything under a specific first level item to have a completely different layout.

In the past I have given a specific item a different wrap like this:

```
IFSUB = 1
IFSUB {
  wrapItemAndSub.cObject  = CASE
  wrapItemAndSub.cObject  {
    key.field = uid
    default = TEXT
    default.value = <li>|</li>
    1234 = TEXT
    1234.value = <li class="mega">|</li>
  }
}
```

But I need to do something different for level 2, 3, and 4 if they are children of uid 1234. Can I rewrite the above to say "if any pid = 1234 above this one then..."?

Answer (score 0):

Wheres the problem then?

```
ul li a {
    color: green;
}
ul li.mega li a {
    color: blue; /* color for second level */
}
ul li.mega li li a {
    color: pink; /* color for third level */
}
ul li.mega li li li a {
    color: fuchsia; /* color for fourth level */
}
```

Comment: It's not a simple css problem, I need to actually change the wraps and add elements.